# Help with listView and sending text

Tags: android, listview

I'm useing a listView to list some webpages.  I'd like to have the webpage open when it's clicked on in the listView.

I'm trying to get some of the "text" from the list item sent to the uri for opening the webpage.  I hope this makes sence to everyone.

I'm just learning so any help would be great.

Something like this?

```
Uri uri =Uri.parse(***text form list item selected***)
```

Thanks,
-Nick

Comment: Can you post your code for listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to implement an `OnItemClickListener()` for your `ListView` and use the information in your `Adapter` to construct your Uri. From there you can launch an activity with your Uri and the action as `ACTION_VIEW` to open a webpage.

Assuming you have your list populated properly you should be looking at attaching an `OnItemClickListener` that looks roughly like this.

```
new OnItemClickListener(){
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {        
        String someJunk = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,new Uri.parse(someJunk)));        
        }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Your code sent me in the right direction to get it working!